# pandas loc with multiple or conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

Suppose I have a following dataframe:

```py
x = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100),
        'B': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100), 
        'C': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100), 
        'D': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100), 
        'E': np.random.normal(0, 1, 100) 
    }
)
```

I want to use `loc` and select only those rows where a value of certain is less than 0.5.
I know I can do this as follows:

```py
df.loc[df.A < 0.5, :]
```

and for multiple columns, I can do as follows:

```py
df.loc[(df.A < 0.5) | (df.B < 0.5) | (df.C < 0.5), :]
```

My question is: Is there a better way to write conditions inside `loc` when you have more than 10 columns. I suppose I can do it the way I have shown above, but it becomes very tedious and I was hoping for a better way to do so.

Comment: `df.loc[df.iloc[:,:3].lt(0.5).all(1)]`.

Comment: @QuangHoang If they want `|`, you need `any`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
df.loc[(df[['A', 'B', 'C']] < 0.5).any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: If they want |, you need any

Comment: @Neither thanks, corrected